# Does Java Language Specification lay down the rules of method overriding in sub classes?

Tags: java, jls, overriding

Does Java Language Specification lay down the rules of method overriding in sub classes?

Can't seem to find this in the JLS.

Comment: Just curious -- where did you search in JLS? There seem to several entries under Overriding in the [Index](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3IX.html) and the first match in Contents is the section 8.4.8. that Jon Skeet quotes.

Comment: Thanks for bringing out the index, i was actually going through the Contents page for a best match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely does. It's described in [section 8.4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8).

If there's one specific aspect you're trying to find and having problems with, please be more specific in your question - "the rules of method overriding" are pretty broad.

Comment: +1: Even looking at the specifications, I had a lot of difficulty finding this.  Google didn't yield the result for some reason (I might just suck at using search engines.)